# Spring Boot REST API - enable / disable CSRF protection by client type (browser / non-browser)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, csrf

I have a Spring Boot REST API. Due to a security policy I need to have CSRF protection enabled for endpoints accessed by the browser. However, this API will also be accessed by non-browsers. Is there a way I can create two sets of endpoints, one accessible by browsers only with CSRF enabled and the other accessible by non-browsers only with CSRF disabled?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure your CSRF protection using the DSL, like this `http.csrf()...` you can tell which requests you want the CSRF protection to be applied by passing a `RequestMatcher`, like so:

```java
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new MyBrowserRequestMatcher()));
```

And your implementation of `RequestMatcher` could verify if the `HttpServletRequest` contains the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` or check the `User-Agent`.

Just keep in mind that the headers can be changed and you have no guarantee that the request actually come from a browser or non-browser app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have separate URL bases for the browser requests and API requests.

For example, you could have all the endpoints that are to be queried by non-browsers under `/api/...` and in your `SpringBootSecurityConfiguration` class and `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method you could conditionally disable CSRF with `http.csrf().disable();` if the pattern matches (great tutorial can be found [here](https://www.yawintutor.com/how-to-enable-and-disable-csrf/#:%7E:text=Disable%20using%20security%20configuration%20code,disable%20()%E2%80%9D.))

Edit: here is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524470/spring-security-3-2-csrf-disable-for-specific-urls) that might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, wouldn't that non-browser endpoint set still be accessible by browsers? Is there a way I can restrict a given endpoint to one client type or another?

Comment: You could set up roles and authorities, and make the API users have different level of security to users that signed up through the browser. Maybe that's a possible approach for you? In the end, a browser is just making the requests on behalf of the user, so in theory there really isn't a difference by type as far as I know, but you could enforce that separation manually. Is your main concern security and ensuring that the browser (end users) don't stumble onto an unsage endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

As @ferrouskid said, I created two URL one for browsers and other for non-browsers:

In spring security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/withoutCsrf/**")
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .cors().disable();
//complete your configuration }
```

In controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"books","withoutCsrf/books"})
public class BookController {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since relying on request headers may not accurately identify the source of requests, creating separate service urls, one for browser and one for non browser clients and disabling CSRF protection for non browser service can also be considered as a solution.

CSRF protection for specific URLs can be disabled while creating SecurityFilterChain.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/trade/item/nxtitems", "/trade/item/**")).build();
}
```